# Does anyone know about a WPF conponent that acts like the gmail to field?

Tags: wpf, autocomplete, drop-down-menu

Where the To-field is a textbox that also contains a dropdown, where each new contact is added to the text field? Similar to the facebook to field, where a box is created for each receiver.

Is there such a library or component out there?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just look at the Latest WPF Toolkit they have introduced AutoCompleteTextBox.

http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535